# Belly flopping top outs

Tags: bouldering

I've always mocked friends who top-out using their belly (stomach) when bouldering. It's not very graceful but I was reading [this article on UKClimbing](http://www.ukclimbing.com/articles/page.php?id=5982) and it shows someone topping out on a V6 using his stomach. I've always considered this bad form, but maybe I'm wrong.

Is topping out on your belly actually bad form? What is considered best form, and why is it better than bellying out?

Comment: If you are at all concerned about the height of a top-out while bouldering, or feel you are not in the best position to stay on the rock, belly-flopping the top-out will give you a LOT of friction to keep you on the rock. Safety is important.

Comment: My question was more would you consider this a successful accent? When I've done this in the past I've decided it wasn't right and tried again.

Comment: Form and style are only important if you are alive afterward to brag about it. If someone is going to question your ascent because you belly-flopped, find different climbing partners.

Comment: Can we remove the safety question. I'm not high, I have good pads and someone spotting me. Can I tick this climb off or have I failed? My friends will prob all go *"well done"* but I'd feel like I'd failed.

Comment: @Liam a top is a top...But good on you for repeating to improve technique.  I have also sent problems that are set in a manner that cannot be completed "smoothly", this is the whole point of the problem is to contort your body in the strangest positions possible!  PS. This question might spawn comments that may be considered too chatty for this site, or maybe it will only be my comment that is flagged :(

Comment: I give in. Fine I'll answer my own question...

Comment: @theJollySin: *belly-flopping the top-out will give you a LOT of friction to keep you on the rock.* I think your physical intuition behind this is probably wrong. Static friction on dry surfaces is normally independent of surface area. In fact, the coefficient of friction between your shirt and the rock is probably *less* than the the corresponding coefficients for shoe rubber or hands.

Comment: If you are a bad-ass: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KI4-ZHYy9IQ :-) (I most assuredly am not.)

Comment: Sorry for OT but if you are into poker, you could be confused by the thread title ;)

Comment: @bashophil Do tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a technique to topping out a flat featureless boulder gracefully. [Climbing.com have a good article on it](http://www.climbing.com/skill/avoiding-the-beached-whale/)

Briefly this is:

---

> Step one. When you reach the lip of a boulder, quickly evaluate which
> foot to swing up onto the lip (from now on this foot will be known as
> the pivot foot). Let gravity work for you by swinging your pivot foot
> onto the low side, not the high side, of the boulder. If the lip is
> horizontal, pick your stronger — or favored — side to swing up. Do a
> half pull-up, and simultaneously raise your pivot foot over the lip,
> keeping your knee slightly bent. Try to find a good heel hook, edge,
> or foot scum to use as a fulcrum — extra purchase is useful for
> floating a mantel. If possible, use your other foot to edge on the
> face of the boulder.
>
> Step two. With your arm opposite your pivot foot, reach out laterally,
> approximately a forearm’s length, and grab a hold on — or slightly
> above — the lip. Palm the rock with your fingers facing slightly
> towards your body. Flag with your non-pivot foot to keep from
> barndooring.
>
> Step three. Contract your pivot leg so that your hips are even with —
> or higher than — the lip. Hold yourself in position with friction from
> your pivot foot. Bend your elbows, and use your ab muscles to bring
> yourself aggressively close to the rock. If you’re having a hard time
> making your foot stick, try draping your pivot-foot leg over the
> stone, contacting the rock with the underside of your calf muscle, to
> create additional friction.
>
> Step four. Pop your pivot-foot hand and elbow 90 degrees so that your
> fingers face your torso. Shift your other hand 45 degrees outwards
> (away from your body), and switch your fingers from clasping the rock
> to palming it. This positions your shoulders over your wrists, and
> improves your overall leverage.
>
> Step five. Rock up, pulling with the thigh and calf muscles of your
> pivot leg, keeping tension with your abs. Turn your pivot knee in
> slightly, and pull your torso over the lip. Flagging your non-pivot
> foot helps as a counter balance, as does smearing (backstepping) on
> top of the lip with your non-pivot foot. If done properly, your body
> will be almost horizontal to the ground.
>
> Step six. Dig the inside edge of your pivot foot into whatever feature
> it’s on. If there are no features, firmly push of your shoe into the
> rock to maintain friction. Now lever up onto this foot, twisting your
> torso inward. Drive hard with your elbows as you push your shoulders
> over the lip with your palms.
>
> Step seven. Extend your elbows and stand up. You’ll likely have to
> make minor adjustments in the position of your hands and body to keep
> your balance as you go from perching to standing.

### [UK climbing have just published an article](http://www.ukclimbing.com/articles/page.php?id=6849)

on it's web site going into details of this technique.